# hypocycloid straight line mechanisme as waves?

Tags: geometry

I wanted to know the other face of hypocycloid ( tusi couple ) ... it generates straight line but how things are going up in terms of waves ?

[image]

Comment: For searching purposes: this is also known as [La Hire's line](http://mathcurve.com/courbes2d/lahire/lahire.shtml).

Comment: What do you mean by "the other face"?